# How to inspect a React tree, see props and state of components in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, react-devtools

I installed official React Developer Tools extension for Firefox and Chrome and successfully use them.

But I cannot find any extension for Internet Explorer 11. My app doesn't correctly work with IE 11.

Supporting of IE11 is mandatory for me.   Is there any extension for IE 11 to inspect react, its props and state in this browser ?

Answer (score 1):

The [React DevTools](https://twitter.com/reactjs) available today in Chrome, Firefox, and (Chromium) Edge, not for IE browser. You could try to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new?labels=Component:%20Developer%20Tools) or tag [@reactjs on Twitter](https://twitter.com/reactjs).

For your react app doesn't correctly work with IE 11, you could create a new thread and post details information to reproduce the problem, then we will help you narrow down the problem and solve it.